# Jquery/Javascript URL parameter display div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically display certain divs with a URL parameter using Jquery/Javascript. I have successfully created the URL parameter function by adding ?s=business, ?s=design, and ?s=content to the end of the url, but when clicking to close the div opened with the URL parameter the div.yoo does not reappear. Additionally I would like to prevent the ?s=design, ?s=content, or ?s=business from displaying in the address bar. Ideas?

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="design">
<div>
<div class="up"></div>
  <div class="yoo">
   <h2>Title 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="yep" id="design">
   <div class="up active"></div>
   <h2>Title 1</h2>
   <p>content 1</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
 <div>
  <div class="up"></div>
  <div class="yoo">
   <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="yep" id="content">
   <div class="up active"></div>
   <h2>Title 2</h2>
   <p>content 2</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="business">
 <div>
  <div class="up"></div>
  <div class="yoo">
   <h2>Title 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="yep" id="business">
   <div class="up active"></div>
   <h2>Title 3</h2>
   <p>content 3</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have the following javascript:

```
<script> 
    $('.design').click(function(){ 
        $('.design').addClass('active');
        $('.design .yep').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.design .yoo').toggle(200);
        $('.design > div > .up').toggle(200);
    });
    $('.content').click(function(){      
        $('.content .yep').slideToggle('slow'); 
        $('.content').addClass('active');
        $('.content .yoo').toggle(200);
        $('.content > div > .up').toggle(200);
    });
    $('.business').click(function(){      
        $('.business .yep').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.business').addClass('active'); 
        $('.business .yoo').toggle(200);
        $('.business > div > .up').toggle(200);
    });
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
// Parse the URL parameter
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the parameter a variable name
var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('s');

 $(document).ready(function() {

    if (dynamicContent == 'business') {
        $('#business').toggle();
    } 
    else if (dynamicContent == 'design') {
        $('#design').toggle();
    } 
    else if (dynamicContent == 'content') {
        $('#content').toggle();
    } 

    else {
        $('#design').toggle();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can check your logic with browser's developer console. You used `.toggle()` for toggling visibility of the `.yoo` DIV, but did you check the DIV is successfully changed to the desired visibility? You can also create a JSFiddle for us for easier debugging

Comment: Are you sure that code here is complete? Your code in this Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/VLvxLjmrPY2B5pY06wbu?p=preview does not work

Comment: Can you supply with whole html including references to jquery etc?

Comment: I have it set up on the site here: http://www.theness.co/dev/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=110 will this work for you all to troubleshoot?